# Comparing Images using ImageMagick MagickCore C API

Tags: c, imagemagick

I'm trying to find how similar two images are but I'm getting segmentation faults. What am I doing wrong?

```
ExceptionInfo     *exception;
Image             *base_image, *reference_image, *composed_image,  *image, *images, *images1;
double            *similarity;
RectangleInfo     offset;
ImageInfo         *image_info, *image_info1;

char base_image_src[] = "jpgs/100000.jpg";
char reference_image_src[] = "jpgs/100000.jpg";

MagickCoreGenesis(NULL, MagickTrue);
exception = AcquireExceptionInfo();

image_info = CloneImageInfo((ImageInfo *) NULL);
(void) strcpy(image_info->filename, base_image_src);
base_image = ReadImage(image_info, exception);

image_info1 = CloneImageInfo((ImageInfo *) NULL);
(void) strcpy(image_info1->filename, reference_image_src);
reference_image = ReadImage(image_info1, exception);

offset.width = (unsigned int) 1200;
offset.height = (unsigned int) 1200;
offset.x = 0;
offset.y = 0;

composed_image = SimilarityImage(base_image, reference_image, &offset, similarity, exception);
```

Edit: I realized it's breaking on SimilarityImage.
0x000000371dc5fdfa in SimilarityImage () from /usr/lib64/libMagickCore.so.2

Comment: Given that offset is struct on the stack, it's hard to believe it seg faulted on that line. Throw it in the debugger and single step through that area.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I believe the segmentation fault / bus error is related to double pointer for the `similarity` variable. Like the `offset`, declare it within the stack, and pass it's reference.

```cpp
// From
double  *similarity;
// To
double   similarity;

// And from
composed_image = SimilarityImage(base_image, reference_image, &offset, similarity, exception);
// To
composed_image = SimilarityImage(base_image, reference_image, &offset, &similarity, exception);
```

Or allocated the double

```cpp
double  *similarity = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double));
```